# VSC: when starting debug (F5), get a spurious web page localhost:53519

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code (VSC) when hitting F5 to start the debugger, it spawn a page localhost:53519 which is does not make any sense to me.  It does not affect the debugging function, it is just that it is there and I have to click to close it.

I cannot find that port number in "Open Configuration".

I did not expect this page to be launched when F5 is executed.

Update: Debugging php with xdebug installed.  Live server was previously installed but later removed, and the problem is still there.

Comment: what kind of program are you trying to launch? What language? Do you have [the Live Server extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) installed and enabled?

Comment: Thank you for your question.  It is the first time I am using StackOverflow to ask a question.  I should be more thorough.

I am debugging php (with xdebug), and yes, I have Live Server extension installed and enabled.

Comment: When the page launches, does your VS Code bottom right bar show that live server is online? Also, please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Comment: Hi 'user', thank you very much.  Turning on the Live Server solved the issue.  I have updated the question to incorporate additional info and the solution.

Comment: what do you mean by "turn it on"? do you mean enabling the extension? Or do you mean disabling the extension? Or do mean clicking the "go live" button?

Comment: by turn on, I mean "go live" correct.  I have not tried disabling the extension to see how that affects my issue.

Comment: Please try disabling it and seeing how it affects the issue. Are you even using that extension at all in this workspace (project)?

Comment: With apologies, I was not correct.  The problem is still there with Live Server totally removed.  I will amend my question accordingly.